# Yii Recoverable error "Object of class **** could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I have two models namely "ProducerOffer" and "Vegetable".I need to create an object of "ProducerOffer" inside "Vegetable " model view action.I need to create an object of "ProducerOffer" model inside "Vegetable" model.But I am geting this error and unable to trace the source. 
The error I am getting

```
Object of class ProducerOffer could not be converted to string
```

The code I wrote in Vegetable Controller

```
public function actionCreateOffer($id)
{

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $ProducerOffer=new ProducerOffer;
    if(isset($_POST['ProducerOffer'])AND (isset($_POST['Vegetable'])) ) 

    {
        $ProducerOffer->attributes=$_POST['ProducerOffer'];
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Vegetable'];
        $ProducerOffer->vegetable_id=$model->id;
        if($model->validate()  AND  $ProducerOffer->validate()) {


        $model->save();
        $ProducerOffer->save();
        }   

        if (($model->hasErrors() === false)&&($ProducerOffer->hasErrors()===false))
        {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }   





    }
    else
    {

        Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
    }
    $this->render('offer',array('ProducerOffer'=>$ProducerOffer,'model'=>$model));



}
```

The code I wrote for my view named "offer.php".

```
<div style='padding-left:50px'>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array('id'=>'non-ajax_form','enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>
<p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,$ProducerOffer); ?>

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('name')); ?>:</b>


<?php echo CHtml::textField("Vegetable[name]",$model->name); ?>


<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($ProducerOffer->getAttributeLabel('offered_qty')); ?>:</b>


<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[offered_qty]",$ProducerOffer->offered_qty); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::encode($ProducerOffer->getAttributeLabel('unit_cost')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[unit_cost]",$ProducerOffer->unit_cost); ?>




<?php echo CHtml::encode($ProducerOffer->getAttributeLabel('unit_delivery_cost')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[unit_delivery_cost]",$ProducerOffer->unit_delivery_cost); ?>






<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=>  'Save',)); ?> 
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'reset', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=> 'Reset')); ?>
   <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'link', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=> 'Cancel','url'=>Yii::app()->user->returnUrl,)); ?>

</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

My relation function in the  ProducerOffer model

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                'producerOfferVegetableRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Vegetable', 'vegetable_id'),
}
```

My relation function in vegetable model

```
public function relations()
    {

        return array(
                'producerOfferRelation'=> array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Vegetable', 'id'),
        );
    }
```

I am unable to figure out the source of error ? How should I resolve this?
I am getting error in this lines   as shown by the browser

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,$ProducerOffer); ?>
```

In the controller

```
 $this->render('offer',array('ProducerOffer'=>$ProducerOffer,'model'=>$model));
```

I am getting error in these lines.

Comment: it's hard without error location, i don't think that error is that code

Comment: On which line of your code do you get the error ?

Comment: its not validating. Just if I click "submit"  without entering the fields I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Error might be at this line:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,$ProducerOffer); ?>
```

The second argument of this method is `string $header` but you are passing $ProducerOffer instead.
Change it like this:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model, $ProducerOffer)); ?>
```

or like this:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($ProducerOffer); ?>
```

(try it yourself, I don't remember exactly is it possible to pass array of models as a first argument)